# Cannot find good include directory and lib in my project after find_package

Tags: cmake

I'm building my own library using this CMakeLists.txt :

```
PROJECT (AstroLib)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

set(AALib_VERSION_MAJOR 1 CACHE STRING "major version" FORCE)
set(AALib_VERSION_MINOR 95 CACHE STRING "minor version" FORCE)
set(AALib_VERSION ${AALib_VERSION_MAJOR}.${AALib_VERSION_MINOR} CACHE STRING "version" FORCE)


set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR_IN_INTERFACE ON)

include(GenerateExportHeader)


file(GLOB AALib_SRCS     "AALIb/source/*.cpp")
file(GLOB AALib_Headers     "AALIb/include/*.h" "AALIb/include/*.hpp")

message ("AALib_VERSION ${AALib_VERSION}")
message ("CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
message ("CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")


add_library (AALib STATIC ${AALib_SRCS})

target_include_directories(AALib PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/AALib/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    PRIVATE AALib/source)

generate_export_header( AALib )

set_property(TARGET AALib PROPERTY VERSION ${AALib_VERSION})

install(TARGETS AALib EXPORT AALibConfig
  LIBRARY DESTINATION "lib/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION "lib/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
  INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/AALib_export.h"  DESTINATION include   COMPONENT    Devel)
install(FILES ${AALib_Headers} DESTINATION include)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file(
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/AALib/AALibConfigVersion.cmake"
  VERSION ${AALib_VERSION}
  COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion
)

export(TARGETS AALib
  FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/AALib/AALibConfig.cmake"
  NAMESPACE Upstream::
)

install(EXPORT AALibConfig DESTINATION AALib/cmake)

set(FOO "rtatzera")
#configure_file(AALibTargets.cmake   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/AALib/AALibConfig.cmake"  COPYONLY)

set(ConfigPackageLocation lib/cmake/AALib)

message ("ConfigPackageLocation ${ConfigPackageLocation}")

install(EXPORT AALibConfig
  FILE
    AALibConfig.cmake
  NAMESPACE
    Upstream::
  DESTINATION
    ${ConfigPackageLocation}
)
```

I run cmake-gui with this cmakelists.txt and I can build and install my library on my computer.

Now I want to use this lib in another project using this cmakelists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

PROJECT (DataMeteo)

find_package(OpenCV  REQUIRED)
find_package(AALib  REQUIRED)


file(GLOB DataMeteo_SRCS
    "*.h"
    "*.cpp")
ADD_EXECUTABLE (DataMeteo ${DataMeteo_SRCS})

message ( "AALib = ${AAlib}")
if (OpenCV_FOUND AND AALib_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries( DataMeteo PUBLIC  ${AALIb_} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
else (OpenCV_FOUND AND AALib_FOUND)
     message("OPENC not found or AALib NOT FOUND ")
endif (OpenCV_FOUND AND AALib_FOUND)
```

In VS project I can find all opencv libs and include but I cannot find include and lib of my own Library. There is no error when I run cmake-gui.

Where is error(s) in my code (cmakelists.txt)?

Configuration Windows 10 64 bits VS2017 CMake 3.11.0

Comment: `I cannot find include and lib of my own Library.` - Please, elaborate this. Do you encounter an error during the build? Or does Visual Studio not highlight symbols, belonging to your library?

Comment: After find_package(AALib  REQUIRED) I should find in  my vs project for inculde path to ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/AALib/include and for link in input ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/AALib/lib/AALIb.lib. There is nothing but I can find good path and lib for opencv. Of course if  I compile my project I can get error fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'AA+.h': No such file or directory

Comment: Export header, installed by CMake with `install(EXPORT)`, provides **INPORTED targets** (`Upstream::AALib` in your case), not a variables `XXX_LIBRARIES` and `XXX_INCLUDE_DIRS`, which are normally set only by `FindXXX.cmake` scripts. An *IMPORTED target* is intended to be used via `target_link_libraries` (in your case: `target_link_libraries DataMeteo Upstream::AALib`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks a lot it works :

Comment: @Tsyvarev I copied upstream::AALib in cmake doc. Now how can an AALib user guess this name without searching in source code? must I give a small sample in my AAlib ?

Comment: `Now how can an AALib user guess this name without searching in source code?` - It should be documentation for your project which describes usage of the project.